# Retrieve data from website with an iOS app that was downloaded after visiting the website

Tags: ios

What I would like to do is to retrieve some string from a specific website that the user visited with an app that is downloaded AFTER visiting that webpage.

To be more specific, the IDEAL user experience would be:

1. User who does not have the app installed visits www.website.com/some_id
2. From www.website.com/some_id, the user is immediately directed to download
   the app from the App Store
3. User opens the app, and the app immediately knows
   "some_id" without the user having to do any more work.

I realize this is a very difficult problem and I have come up with some solutions that "sort of work" but are not ideal for user experience:

1. Use url schemes. On the webpage, instruct user to return to site after they download the app and click on a link that opens the app: `myapp://some_id`
2. Ask user for some sort of identifying information on the website and in the app - such as a login, or phone number - store it on server, then retrieve it on app.
3. Ask user to copy and paste `some_id` from the website before downloading the app. Once app is opened, the app can access the clipboard directly and retrieve `some_id` programatically

The question is if there is something that can solve the IDEAL problem?

If not, are there any other solutions that are better than the ones I listed above. The criteria for "better" is asking the user to do as little work as humanly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to store the IP address with the data on my database when the user visited the website then queried for the IP address from the app after the app was downloaded.

This isn't guaranteed to work 100% of the time but is a "good enough" solution for the application I am developing.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible.
Maybe, if `some_id` is the `userID`, you should provide a login form in the app, so you will know the `userID` without asking it to the user. Or, you can simply provide a `UITextField` where you will ask the `some_id` param.

Answer (score 0):

As a disclaimer, I work on [branch.io](https://branch.io) and think about mobile linking around 18 hours a day. Branch links do this for you automatically and then some.

We've built a fingerprinting solution that collects information about devices both when a user is in the browser and then after they open the app. This information includes *IP Address, OS, OS version, device model, screen size and other parameters*. We match the unique fingerprint collected in the app to the unique fingerprint collected in the browser to determine where user originated from if the prior two mechanisms were not used.

Additionally, when the user is in the browser, we set a *first party cookie and match it to the IDFA/hardware id* after the user installs. Anytime thereafter, when we see the cookie, we know for sure what the device will look like. As we now have hundreds of millions of users passing through the service on a daily basis, we rely less and less on the fingerprinting mechanism and more on our match pool.

Comment: so u can get IDFA from the cookie ? after iOS 11+ you can't access cookies from application , the app will have its own storage , correct me if i am wrong ! any solution how to get the IDFA from browser ?

Comment: Branch knows the IDFA/GAID from the browser cookie, but just through our scale of Branch link usage. We don't directly expose that ID to you in the browser, but will tell you if the app is installed when the user lands on your site ie https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking#initbranch_key-options-callback, or use this data to let you deep link / attribute the user across web and app.

Comment: i just tried the branch web sdk, it not returning IDFA/GAID from browser , i think ur information is wrong , since apple has stopped sharing safari cookies with installed application in ios 11+